# Fullcalendar with bootstrap popover z-Index issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, popover, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to integrate full calender scheduler and bootstrap popover. However, I am getting the UI issue with this.

I tried setting the z-index for popover as well as for my popover inner html. Nothing works.

Here is my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/87977p1x/5/

Clicking on event 2 you can see the popover. Here is the popover code inside fullcalander

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {

                    element.popover({
                        trigger: "click",

                        title: '<div class="label label-lg label-primary col-xs-12">' + event.title + '</div>',
                        html: true,
                        content: '<div style="width:70px">My content goes here.. blahhh blahhhh<div><div> Some more content in this div having more nested HTML</div>',
                        template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'

                    });
                }
```

[image]

Tried a lot for past 3 days couldn't find out why its going behind the event, even though I increase z-index..

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other question [Fullcalendar with Twitter Bootstrap Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158141/fullcalendar-with-twitter-bootstrap-popover?rq=1), I applied `container:'body'` it works..

```
 element.popover({
                    trigger: "click",
                    container:'body',
                    // other settings...

                });
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87977p1x/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to attach it to .fc-scroller so that when the calendar is scrolled, the popover will scroll with the event.

```
                element.popover({
                    trigger: "click",
                    container:$(element).closest('.fc-scroller');
                });
```